# Chunking Data in Node JS

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm new to node and am having trouble conceptualizing why you would "Chunk" data on a POST request only and not a GET request?

```
if (request.method === "POST") {
  if (request.url === "/classes/messages" || request.url === "/classes/room1") {
    var statusCode = 201;
    var headers = defaultCorsHeaders;
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("receiving data....", body);
      body += data;
    });
    //request ended, you can now do something with the data
    request.on('end', function() {
      var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
      bodyObj.objectId = Math.random() * 10;
      responseObj['results'].push(bodyObj);
      // request ended -> do something with the data. set the headers. 
      response.writeHead(statusCode, headers);
      //writing the data to json
      //response.write();
      //ending the response. 
      response.end(JSON.stringify(responseObj));
    });
    //headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain";
  }
}
```

Comment: `GET` requests have no body. The body is sent in chunks so "chunking" the data is not even an option because that's how the request is sent. I suppose the headers (which has all of the data a `GET` request needs) is not "chunked" but my http knowledge is not that sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when use POST method user send data to server and we need analyze so need chuck all data.
When use GET server send data to user, server not get data, not need chuck